# Hall's marriage theorem with infinitely many people

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I fully understand Hall's marriage theorem, if I have $n$ boys and $m$ girls and if every subset of $k$ boys knows at least $k$ girls then there exists a matching between the boys and girls. 
What happens if we now consider a village with infinitely many boys and girls? If the marriage condition still holds does Hall's marriage theorem still hold and that there is a matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not hold.
Let $B=\{b_0,b_1,b_2\ldots\}$ be the set of boys, and $G=\{g_1,g_2,\ldots\}$ be the set of girls, i.e., each number of boys and girls is countably infinite.
Assume below conditions:

- Boy $b_0$ knows every girl, and
- boy $b_i$ knows girl $g_i$ for all $i \geq 1$.

Then it satisfies Hall's marriage condition.
However, there is no matching cover $B$.

I referred: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem

I don't know the infinite Hall's marriage theorem holds if the condition has more restriction: Each boy know only finitely many girls.

Comment: Yes, it works if each boy knows only finitely many girls. Depending on your mathematical background/tastes, use an ultrafilter, or the Tychoff product theorem, or Rado's selection principle, or the compactness of first order logic.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790112/halls-marriage-theorem-and-tychonoff-theorem and point $2$ in the linked paper.

Comment: I really don’t understand the proof you linked. Could you explain it a little please.